# Assigns to events via checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need assign to events. I have user edit with checkboxes, where i choose event and after click on save i'd like add insert to database with event_id and user_id. I don't know if is it good idea, but if somebody have better ideas please give me a piece of advice.

My view,  On this moment i only know to which event i'm assign:

```
  <% Event.all.each do |event| -%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag :event_ids, event.name -%></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :event_ids, event.id, @user.event.include?(event), :name => 'user[event_ids][]' -%></td>
  </tr>
  <% end -%>
```

My schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
  end

  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "event_date"
    t.string   "organizator"
    t.string   "email"
  end

  create_table "bookings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
  end
```

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :events, :through => :bookings

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bookings
    has_many :users, :through => :bookings
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have User > Booking > Event, I have Gallery > Entry > Photo.

In the controller for edit:

```
@photo_ids = []
@gallery.entries.each do |entry|
  @photo_ids << entry.photo.id
end
```

The pertinent part of _form.html.haml is:

```
- @photos.in_groups_of(15, false) do |group|
  %tr
    - group.each do |photo|
      %td
        = label_tag("photo_ids_#{photo.id}", image_tag(photo.image.url(:thumb)))
        = raw('<br/>')
        = check_box_tag "photo_ids[]", photo.id, @photo_ids.include?(photo.id), :id => "photo_ids_${photo.id}"
```

And when saving in the controller:

```
if @gallery.save
  photo_ids = params[:photo_ids]
  photo_ids ||= []
  @gallery.entries.each |entry|
    entry_photo_id_s = entry.photo_id.to_s
    # if already in gallery and checked, keep it, and remove from list to add
    if photo_ids.include?(entry_photo_id_s)
      photo_ids.delete(entry_photo_id_s)
    else
      entry.destroy
    end
    # if not already in gallery, add an entry
    photo_ids.each do |photo_id|
      entry = Entry.new
      entry.gallery_id = @gallery.id
      entry.photo_id = photo_id
      entry.save
    end
  end
  blah, blah, blah (render, redirect, whatever)
end
```

With a little translation of entities (and from HAML to ERB), that should work for your User > Booking > Event.